# Condition for sliding of two blocks placed one over another and connected by spring

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction, spring

[image]

> A constant force F is applied to smaller mass till M slides. The spring constant is k. Now it is asked to find k.

I'm confused with the condition at which the block will start sliding. Can someone please help! (Yes I know you might feel this is homework and i'm asking for the solution.I'm not. Just a small conceptual hint will do)

Note: There is no wall on the left. The arrangement is placed on a floor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Just a small conceptual hint will do

No problem. A hint:

Set up Newton's law, $\sum F=ma$. You will see that the sum of all the **three** forces must equal... yes, what should it equal?

> I'm confused with the condition at which the block will start sliding

What is the difference in the equation mentioned above for a point *just after it started moving*, and the point *just before it starts to move*? Think about the right-hands side.